# Apache CXF hangs upon shutting down tomcat

Tags: tomcat, cxf, jax-ws, spring-java-config

I wire in a CXFServlet to my application, which already has wired in a dispatcher servlet.  The endpoint works just fine and everything seems to work until we shutdown tomcat.  I have found that I can wire in the CXFServlet and tomcat shuts down without a problem until I wire in the bus.  After which I see the problem with the shutdown hanging. 
To shutdown tomcat I have to kill the process.  Any ideas?

The threads that are left after shutting down tomcat are:

- Daemon Thread [Thread-2]
- Thread [Event-1]
- Thread [DestroyJavaVM]

Versions of libraries and server used:

- Apache CXF 3.0.1
- Spring 4.0.3.RELEASE
- Spring Security 3.2.0.RELEASE
- Spring Java-config
- Apache Tomcat 7.0.47

My pom.xml has the following dependencies from the cxf library and servlet-api library:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

This is how I wired in the CXFServlet:

```
@Order(3)
public class IMSWebServicesApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer
{
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException
{
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("CXFServlet", new CXFServlet());
    servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    servlet.addMapping("/services/*");
}
```

The following is how I wired in the endpoint:

```
import org.apache.cxf.Bus;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;

import com.verisk.underwriting.id_access_api.api.authentication.AuthenticationService;
import com.verisk.underwriting.id_access_api.token.DefaultTokenInfo;
import com.verisk.underwriting.id_access_api.token.TokenService;
import com.verisk.underwriting.ims.web.service.LoginWebService;
import com.verisk.underwriting.ims.web.service.LoginWebServiceImpl;
import com.verisk.underwriting.modules.appbase.status.ServerStatusService;

@Configuration
@ImportResource({"classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"})
public class IMSWebServicesConfiguration
{           
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public EndpointImpl login(Bus bus, LoginWebService loginWebService)
    {       
        EndpointImpl endpointImpl = new EndpointImpl(bus, loginWebService);
        endpointImpl.setAddress("/login");
        endpointImpl.publish();
        return endpointImpl;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public LoginWebService loginWebService(TokenService<DefaultTokenInfo> tokenService,     AuthenticationService authenticationService, 
            ServerStatusService<DefaultTokenInfo> serverStatusService)
    {
        return new LoginWebServiceImpl(tokenService, authenticationService,     serverStatusService);
    }
}
```

The LoginWebService interface:

```
@WebService(name="login")
@SOAPBinding(style=Style.RPC, use=Use.LITERAL)
public interface LoginWebService
{
...
}
```

The LoginWebService implementation:

```
@WebService(endpointInterface="com.verisk.underwriting.ims.web.service.LoginWebService", serviceName="login")
public class LoginWebServiceImpl implements LoginWebService
{ 
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you [take a thread dump](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/18178) at the following points:

1. Immediately before issuing the shutdown command.
2. Right after the shutdown command is issued.
3. 60s after the shutdown command is issued and then
4. 120s after shutdown command.

Then, you may use a [thread analyser tool](http://samuraism.jp/samurai/en/index.html) and / or post the dumps on a public location and share here.

Basically, the idea is to find what the threads are doing and which are preventing the container from shutting down, probably due to a lock.